# Why docker is taking up so much storage in my mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have a PostgreSQL container with 2 databases, but it must be less than 10GB, why the docker container is 50GB?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things I would suggest:

1. run `docker [management command] prune` for all the management commands that accept the `prune` command (`builder`, `container`, `image`, `network`, `system`, `volume`). It can be very surprising how much crud is hanging around, taking up space (I just ran it for `volumes` and got 7GB back).
2. download and run `docker-squash` on the images. If images are built iteratively (creating a new layer from the prior layer, then a new one on top of that, etc...) they can get really massive. `docker-squash` will get rid of those intermediate layers that aren't doing anything but taking up space. It should be installable using `brew`.

Comment: Probably should have figured this out ages ago, just got an absolute boatload of space back by running all these.

Answer (score 0):

It might be some images you previously used or volumes that used my your databases behind the scenes.

try: `docker images` to list your local images and `docker system df` to see all disk usage:

```
~ $ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                
RECLAIMABLE
Images              41                  3                   12.67GB             12.15GB (95%)
Containers          4                   0                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       2                   2                   438.6MB             0B (0%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```